# how to multiply value of each object present in an array with value of another array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I am looking for some solution to a problem that I faced during completing an assignment. The problem is similar to this that I have tried explaining below.

```
var arrOfObj = [{a:10 },{a:20},{a:30}, ......]
var arrToMultiply = [2,4,6, .....]
```

Result I am expecting

```
const result = [{a:10,result:20},{a:20,result:80},{a:30,result:180}, .....]
```

how can I multiply each value of array with the value of integer at same index inside object of the array?

Comment: Sounds like something you could do with a simple for loop. Have you done any research or made any attempts?

Comment: If they're guaranteed to be of the same length I'm not sure what the issue is--`map` either one, use the `index` to pull out the other value, do the multiplication, and return the aggregate oject. It would be best if you showed your efforts so far.

Comment: @HereticMonkey  I got the solution and my program worked. Array are of same size.

Comment: @DaveNewton I was using for loop instead of map function to increment the value of index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
let arrOfObj = [{a: 10}, {a: 20}, {a: 30}];
let arrToMultiply = [2, 4, 6];

let result = arrOfObj.map((item, index)=> ({...item, result: item.a*arrToMultiply[index]}));
console.log(result);
```